# xp_cmdshell Access is denied - 2012 Dev Edition installed on Windows 8

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-8.1

EDIT:

I got it to work by going into Computer Management and changing the logon of the SQL Service to use a local account.

---

I have a copy of SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition (with SP1) installed on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I created a folder specifically to test out some file import/export using stored procedures. The location is: C:\SQL

When I run

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\sql'
```

It returns the folder contents. When I run

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\sql > dir c:\sql\dir.txt'
```

It returns Access is denied

So I looked around for a bit, saw this

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'osql -E -Q"select suser_sname()"'
```

And added the MSSQLSERVER to user groups and to specifically have full access to C:\SQL.

Does anyone have further suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the account that you are running the SQL has to have prevledges to the C:\SQL directory.

However, your issue is an syntax error.  A extra 'dir' command.  Try this corrected one.

```
-- pipe output to dir.txt
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir c:\sql > c:\sql\dir.txt'
```

On my SQL Server 2012 Developer, it returns null as a value.  But the directory listing exists.  I changed to c:\temp for my execution.

[image]

Comment: That was a pasting error on my part, sorry. It's funny though, I'd set up xp_cmdshell to execute with much more complicated permissions issues (multiple servers over networks etc.), but I'd never set it up locally and I thought it might be Windows 8 being an odd bird.